# Generate two jar with the same maven project

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I would like to generate two jars from the same maven project when executing a mvn clean install.
The only difference between the two jars, will be the content of the **META-INF** folder.

For the moment, I've **my-app.jar**, I would like to have now **my-jar-xxx.jar** and **my-jar-yyy.jar**.
How can I achieve this ?

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

You should not be creating two maven jars from the same maven project.  Why?  [This](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/) sonatype blog post should explain.

The same article also explains two ways in which you can still do it, if you want to

- Using profiles
- By doing two executions of maven jar plugin

Here is the [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132958/ant-to-maven-multiple-build-targets) stackoverflow post as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all +1 for Raghuram recommendation. In his linked sonatype blog you get hints about doing what you want using the `classifier` to distinguish between your two jars. The jars belong to the same artifact in this case.

You can also use two different poms for two different builds and call

```
mvn -f pom-xxx.xml clean install
mvn -f pom-yyy.xml clean install
```

In each pom you can specify an own `artifactId`. That separates both artifacts a bit more than the `classifier` solution does.

Nevertheless the advice *not* to do this seems reasonable and I would follow the parent/module project layout suggestion.