# How to have different build task and dependency "on-demand" with Maven

Tags: maven, project-management, build-process, build-automation, customization

Hi there i need some information or general tips on a problem with maven.

Context:
We just migrated one big eclipse project into 4 maven project. (Thats one step in the good direction!)
We were building that/those project with an ant script (build.xml) We were selecting the task to do "on-demand"

To keep it simple here are the 4 project : Core, Client, Server, Admin.
Each of those maven project build into a jar. This have been establish and it is working perfectly. Core is a dependency to Client and Server.

We use Jenkins-CI and Artifactory on a remote server.

Problem:
I need to create some kind of "parent project" that will build all those other maven project and add some task "on demand" that we were doing with an ant script. 
Exemple: We want to build locally (So we don't use jenkins and artifactory on this side) for our developper so they can test manually their update (yes we have no test for now, we are working on a legacy system). On this build, we do not want to obfuscate the code or sign our jar..etc
We also want a "customer build" (The real release that we push on the server, so it does use jenkins and artifactory) That will add some task on some of the 4 project like obfuscating the code, signing the jar ..etc
For this "customer build", we need to be able to select our dependency of a library "on-the-fly" or more like "On demand". Our program is an extension to another software and all our customer don't use the same version. To make it simple the library "y" can be y-2.0.1.jar or y-2.0.2.jar.. etc 
All of those "task" i need can be done in different maven-plugin with no problem.

Question: What would be a good practice to solve my problem. We would really like to get rid of our ant script. Also we are cleaning a big big dirty project so i would like a clean solution without a lots of duplicated stuff or lots of manually task to do each time we want to build either locally or on the remote server for our customer.

Idea: I though i could use different maven profile in all those 4 project as i saw there:
[Ant to Maven - multiple build targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132958/ant-to-maven-multiple-build-targets) But i will have a seriously huge pom.xml for each project with lots of duplicated stuff so I really don't like this idea. I though we could have a parent maven project but this would contain no code so i think I'm wrong with this idea also.

Thank for answering and for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going with [Maven Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) is the right thing to do for this kind of customization. Then you'll probably have developerProfile and releaseProfile or such.
And yes, your poms will be big and complicated.
Looks like your demands are a little bit to much for what Maven can provide out-of-the-box, and it's not the best tool for doing highly-customized builds. Since (as I understand) you are on pretty early days with your new build infrastucture, I'd advice to look at [Gradle](http://gradle.org/). You could reuse your ant tasks and both Jenkins-CI and Artifactory work great with Gradle.