# How to easily copy/rename/remove files with Maven (as in Ant)

Tags: maven, ant, profiles

I am working on a project and using Maven to build it. The project is a quite big Java web application and it is supposed to work with both Mysql and Oracle databases.

The problem is that there are some specific annotations related to either of the two databases in the source code, plus some other differences, so that I am forced to manually comment/uncomment part of the code before building the application for one of the two databases.

Basically what I would like to achieve is to have my build script, maybe via a Maven profile, to automatically switch the source classes before building depending on the database I want my war to work against.

Putting it simply, the idea is to have MyClass.oracle and MyClass.mysql, and depending on my build profile I should move one of the two in the source dir, rename it MyClass and build. This should be done for some packages, classes, and also configuration files.

Is there any way I can achieve it via "pure" Maven? The only solution I came across till now is to use an antrun plugin and reference an Ant build.xml inside of it.

Thank you,

Mattia

Comment: The Maven way is to separate the common parts of the code base into a common module and then have two separate projects for MySQL and Oracle. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132958/ant-to-maven-multiple-build-targets

Answer (score 0):

A pure maven solution would be to develop your own maven plugin. Depending on your requirements this can be an overkill, however it is not hard at all, you can see how to achieve this [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of Maven. One of Maven's purposes is to not have a build script. You should simply use the plugins as available, and setup your project the right way, and magically, everything will build!

There is one solution: Use Ant. Well, not to redo your whole project with Ant, but with the [antrun](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) plugin, you can run a few Ant tasks at various phases of your Maven build life cycle.

It's been a long, long time since I've used this, so I am not going to try to write a test `pom.xml`, but I don't remember it being very difficult to use.

Of course, the correct Maven solution is to divide your project up into "common core" code, and then a separate Oracle and MySql client that uses the "common core". By the way, I hope you're not patching source code. Instead, you're using a properties file to do this for you.