# Create more JARs with Maven

Tags: maven, plugins, jar, package

I have the following directory structure:

```
my_sources
    my_project
        src
            main
                java
                    a
                        A.java
                    b
                        B.java
```

and I would like to package

```
a.A.class
```

in A.jar and

```
b.B.class
```

in B.jar during a single

```
mvn package
```

Is it possible to create more JARs from the same source directory?

Thanky you,
SK

Comment: Have you considered making a multi-module maven project? Googling "maven modules" can get you started...

Comment: For a multi-module project I should split the `src` folder in two separted folders, right? This is what I would like to avoid and use another soultion, if possible.

Comment: Well there is a way to do it like that but it's kind of messy... let me write an answer for you, just give me 10 min :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain two solutions for you.

You could consider making a multi-module maven project, with a structure like this:

```
my_project
pom.xml
    module_A
        pom.xml
        src
            main
                java
                    a
                        A.java
    module_B
        pom.xml
        src
            main
                java
                    b
                        B.java
```

And your "parent pom" (the one at the project root level) will contain this:

```
<modules>
    <module>module_A</module>
    <module>module_B</module>
</modules>
```

Then you can just run `mvn clean install` from the project root and look in `module_A/target` and `module_B/target` to find your jars which have been built.

The other solution involves using exclusions and the maven-jar-plugin (or another plugin that does the same job). Here's maven-jar-plugin [example configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132958/ant-to-maven-multiple-build-targets/2140819#2140819), for a question similar to your own.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Actually I did the same but our software architect is against to split the original `src` folder.

Comment: Meantime I tested the following: 
`<plugin><artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId> <version>2.3.2</version> <executions> <execution> <id>A</id> <goals> <goal>jar</goal> </goals> <phase>package</phase> <configuration> <classifier>A</classifier> <includes> <include>**/a/*</include> </includes> </configuration> </execution> <execution> <id>B</id> <goals> <goal>jar</goal> </goals> <phase>package</phase> <configuration> <classifier>B</classifier> <includes> <include>**/b/*</include> </includes> </configuration> </execution> </executions> </plugin>` and seams to do the job. Thank you anyway.