# maven create copy of same jar with different name for sping project

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have one spring project due to some requirement I have to create copy of jars with different name.

Currently I am building and renaming as per the requirement, I need to automate that in pom during packaging time.

I tried below pom but its creating only default jars only 
is there anyway where we can assign name to create multiple jar copy of same code

---

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycode.userservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>user-service-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2-RELEASE</version>
    <name>UserService</name>
    <properties>
        <spring-boot.version>2.0.0.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
        <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <!-- Spring Boot -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Spring Cloud -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring Boot dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
 <execution>
        <id>build-first</id>
          <configuration>
           <attachToBuild>true</attachToBuild>
            <filename>mainuser.jar</filename>
          </configuration>
          <goals>
            <goal>repackage<</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>build-second</id>
          <configuration>
            <attachToBuild>true</attachToBuild>
            <filename>alternative-user.jar</filename>
          </configuration>
          <goals>
            <goal>repackage<</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-parameters</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

its building only **default** jar, it is not building **alternative-user.jar** and **mainuser.jar**

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132958/ant-to-maven-multiple-build-targets/2140819#2140819